# there is a possibility to store data in HDFS with key-value?

Tags: nosql, hdfs, key-value-store

Storing data in NoSQL databases can provide a key-value storage model. However, HDFS is a dostributed file storage in Hadoop ecosystem. Key-value is used by mapreduce clusters. Therefore, this distribution is generated in processing phase only.

I need to know if there is a possibility to store at rest data in HDFS where each value will identified by a key.

Comment: You did not specify a language, but for Java, for instance; check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16925133/4636715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop support SequenceFiles since its early days (if not since inception) https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile.

These are only useful in map/reduce scenarios and today you'd probably want to use one of the columnar formats (parquet or orc) to store your data which you can also degrade to only hold one key and one value and also use with multiple values per key (they also hold metadata that will enable you to skip data while scanning (e.g. parquet filter pushdown https://drill.apache.org/docs/parquet-filter-pushdown/)

Note that all these formats will not give you online query capabilities (like No-SQL databases) for that you need a no-sql database - if you want one that stores its data on HDFS there's HBase (by the way HFile format it uses is also a key-multi-value format stored on HDFS)